# How to add multiple filters in PlayFramework

Tags: java, playframework

I would like to know if there is a way to define and add more the one Filter to the PlayFramework configuration.
I have this: `play.http.filters = "filters.HttpFilters" in the application.config`

but that is pointing just to one Filter class. If I add a second filter class how can I configure that in the `application.config` ?

For example, I have defined two filters in my code:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `Seq` approach.

```
play.http.filters += [ "filters.HttpFilters", "filters.EssentialLoggingFilter" ]
```